# MVC Website On IIS Acquire Domain User Without Login Prompt

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, windows-authentication

I have an MVC site running on IIS 10. The IIS server and our users are all on the same domain. My question: is there a way for the MVC website to determine the domain user without having the login prompt appear when accessing the website? I turned on Windows Authentication - this causes the login prompt, but it does give me the domain user. The Allow Anonymous returns the IISUSR account. I'd like to access the domain user, but not have the login prompt appear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browser prompt for Windows authentication is normal. If you want to suppress that, only the browser settings can help, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/security-privacy/prompt-for-username-and-password Talk to your domain administrators, and they should know much more about how to configure.

Comment: You need to ask domain administrator to add the domain into  Intranet of IE to make IE know that it is a safe site and can pass windows user account to it.